# How to increment by one the colum names (header) of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe

```
     0    1    2
0  aaa  ddd  ggg
1  bbb  eee  hhh
2  ccc  fff  iii
```

And I'm trying to have this :

```
     1    2    3
0  aaa  ddd  ggg
1  bbb  eee  hhh
2  ccc  fff  iii
```

With `pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix`, unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected output :

```
print(df.add_prefix(+1))
    10   11   12
0  aaa  ddd  ggg
1  bbb  eee  hhh
2  ccc  fff  iii
```

My question might be silly but do you know how to do that with pandas, please ?

Here is the initial dataframe used :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 1: ['ddd', 'eee', 'fff'], 2: ['ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']})
```

**A small detail** : The real dataset has hundreds of columns named (0, 1, 2, ....)

Comment: Please try: `df.columns += 1`

Comment: `df.rename(lambda x: x+1,axis=1)` would work too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply increment by one. An Index behaves like a Series in this respect.

```
df.columns += 1
```

Result:

```
     1    2    3
0  aaa  ddd  ggg
1  bbb  eee  hhh
2  ccc  fff  iii
```